# Return and calculate values based on selected criteria

Tags: r

I've been searching around but still didn't find the answer. I'd like to see and calculate certain results based on my criteria. `if` and `match` functions wouldn't get what I look for. The original dataset looks like this:

```
Type  Name  Value
A     DK    3
A     MO    2
A     OM    5
A     LSO   3
B     GOP   6
B     ADG   5
C     BFC   7
D     TMD   6
```

What I want to get is if Type =A, then list the names and calculate the weight based on value, which should look like below:

```
DK    0.081
MO    0.054
OM    0.135
LSO   0.081
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: `prop.table` and subset? `prop.table(Value)[Type == 'A']`

Comment: Please always add R code that creates the data.frame to help answering your question easier :-)

Comment: "Weight based on value" means the weight of the value within the group or all groups (which the small values indicate)?

Comment: Sorry, I was importing it from a csv file. Weight based on value means the weight of within all groups. rawr's answer (`prop.table(Value)[Type == 'A']`) solved the second part of my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summary of proportions by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057784/summary-of-proportions-by-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)


d<-data.frame(Type=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","D"),
              Name = c("DK","MO","OM","LSO","GOP","ADG","BFC","TMD "),
              Value=c(3,2,5,3,6,5,7,6)
             )

dd<- d %>% 
      mutate(den=sum(Value)) %>% 
      filter(Type=="A") %>% 
      group_by(Name) %>% 
      summarise(Y=Value/min(den))
dd
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, but I got this `Error: could not find function "%>%"` How to fix that?

Comment: Do you have dplyr package installed? Try running `install.packages("dplyr")` . If it is installed you should not get the error.

Comment: Forgot to load the package. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Gaurav, when I apply the same code to my own data set, I got `Error: expecting a single value`. I don't get any error message if I leave out the `summarize()` part. Any idea what caused the issue?

Comment: @T-T , my bad , use `summarise()` instead of `summarize()`

Comment: Seems like they are the same. I tried both and still got the same error message. I did some readings and found that summarise() collapses a data frame to a single row. I think that caused the issue. But how come it works in the example but not in the data set such as mtcars. The `str()` of my data set is also data.frame though.

Comment: @T-T I tested and in works on mtcars. Although, mtcars only has numeric variables and `row.name` as the type of car.

Comment: thank you so much for taking time out to look into it. Maybe there's an issue with my data set that I'm not aware of. What I came up with was adding another column `dd<- d %>% mutate(den=Value/sum(Value)) %>% filter(Type=="A") %>% group_by(Name, den) %>% summarise()`

Answer (score 2):

If performance matters and you have a lot of data use a data.table from the package data.table:

```
dt <- data.table( type=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D")
                  , name=c("DK", "MO", "OM", "LSO", "GOP", "ADG", "BFC", "TMD")
                  , value=c(3, 2, 5, 3, 6, 5, 7, 6))

value.total <- sum(dt$value)

dt[type=="A", .(name, weight=value/value.total)]
```

This will result in:

```
   name     weight
1:   DK 0.08108108
2:   MO 0.05405405
3:   OM 0.13513514
4:  LSO 0.08108108
```

If you want to calculate the weight ("proportion") for each row (not only "A") use:

```
dt[, .(name, weight=value/value.total)]
```

Which results in:

```
   name     weight
1:   DK 0.08108108
2:   MO 0.05405405
3:   OM 0.13513514
4:  LSO 0.08108108
5:  GOP 0.16216216
6:  ADG 0.13513514
7:  BFC 0.18918919
8:  TMD 0.16216216
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Type <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','C','D')
Name <- c('DK', 'MO', 'OM', 'LSO', 'GOP', 'ADG','BFC','TMD')
Value <- c(3,2,5,3,6,5,7,6)
Dat <- data.frame(Type, Name,Value)
Dat
     Type Name Value
1    A   DK     3
2    A   MO     2
3    A   OM     5
4    A  LSO     3
5    B  GOP     6
6    B  ADG     5
7    C  BFC     7
8    D  TMD     6

new.dat <- data.frame(Name, Weight=(Value/sum(Value)))
new.dat
    Name     Weight
1   DK       0.08108108
2   MO       0.05405405
3   OM       0.13513514
4   LSO      0.08108108
5   GOP      0.16216216
6   ADG      0.13513514
7   BFC      0.18918919
8   TMD      0.16216216
```